# How to remove entries in webpack plugin?

Tags: webpack, webpack-plugin

I know how to add entry dynamically in webpack plugin, like below:

```
class AddEntryPlugin {
    apply(compiler) {
        compiler.plugin('entry-option', () => {
            compiler.apply(new SingleEntryPlugin(context, request, name))
        })
        compiler.plugin('watch-run', ({ compiler }, done) =>
            compiler.apply(new SingleEntryPlugin(context, request, name))
            done()
        )
    }
}
```

However I need to remove added entries when invoking watch-run hook, so how to remove the entries?